# How to filter and download OSM data by attribute tag?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, data

Is there any online service that allows to download only one thematic layer of the OSM data for a specific geographic region? For example all objects related to vegetation (trees, grassland,...), but not streets, railways etc. There must be an easy and straightforward way to do so (I hope?).
I'd prefer to use the data directly in QGIS.

I am aware of [Geofabrik](http://download.geofabrik.de) which provides some data packages. But I am interested if there is any way to specify the data I want before actually downloading it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for http://www.overpass-api.de/index.html

It is not as easy as downloading extracts from Geofabrik, but lets you filter for what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You are right, it is indeed not as easy. So far I don't know how to use it... :) I'll keep googling and try to work it out.

Comment: Ok, I finally got what I want using the Overpass-API. Thank you for telling me about it! http://overpass-turbo.eu/ was helpful to me...

Answer (score 0):

We at WeoGeo hosts monthly updates of the OSM data.  You can select the area (via by drawing a polygon or uploading a kml) and layer of interest prior to downloading.

http://market.weogeo.com/datasets/osm-openstreetmap-planet.html

Comment: Welcome to our site.  When recommending a product with which you are affiliated, we expect you to identify that affiliation explicitly.  StackExchange does offer marketing opportunities: please visit http://stackexchange.com/about/contact.