# Downloading shapefile from OpenStreetMap?

Tags: shapefile, openstreetmap, download

I am trying to download the shapefile (orange line) from 
https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/271888#map=12/48.7810/9.2247

Can you explain how I can extract the shapefile from here?

Comment: OSM use it's own data format, so what you see is not from a shapefile that you can directly download.To get the data you need to query the osm database, if you are a QGIS user you may want to try the QuickOSM pluggin if you are not have a look at overpass API also this question https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/57828/how-to-filter-and-download-osm-data-by-attribute-tag

Comment: You can download shapefiles by sub regions here (https://download.geofabrik.de/index.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up using the following:
http://overpass-turbo.eu/

```
[out:json];relation(271888);>;out;
```

downloaded it and then converted it to shp
https://mygeodata.cloud/converter/geojson-to-shp

Answer (score 3):

The OSM Wiki page about Shapefiles has a list of services for [Obtaining_shapefiles_from_OSM_data](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Shapefiles#Obtaining_shapefiles_from_OSM_data). A few examples from this list:

- http://download.geofabrik.de/
- https://osmdata.openstreetmap.de/
- http://osm2shp.ru/
- https://download.bbbike.org/osm/bbbike/

There are various other and of course you can [create your own shapefiles](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Shapefiles#Create_your_own_shapefiles) from OSM data.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to use the QuickOSM Plugin. Here is a guide on how to use it.

http://jonathansoma.com/lede/foundations-2018/qgis/osm/

Answer (score -1):

Here if someone is looking for a simple site that provides geojson
https://osm-boundaries.com/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).